# Is $GL_{S^1}(H)$ (for $H$ Hilbert space ) path-connected?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups

Due to the negative answer to my last question I want to know if at least the following is true:

Let H be an infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert space with $S^1$-action. Let $\text{Gl}_{S^1}(H)$ be the space of invertible, bounded and equivariant linear maps (from H to H).

Is $\text{Gl}_{S^1}(H)$ path-connected? If not, what is known about the components?

Of course, I would be happy enough if you point out references.

Comment: See the comment I just left on
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78347/theorem-of-kuiper-for-hilbert-spaces-with-group-action/78351#78351

Comment: Again, thank you. This helps me a lot.